# log(x,2log(2x, 2log(2,4x))) >1 , find answers of x

Tags: logarithms

how i slove it , please help me?

### log(x,2log(2x, 2log(2,4x))) >1

my try:

if x>1

=>2log(2x, 2log(2,4x))>x

=> 2log(2,4x)>(2x)^(x/2)

=>4x>2^(((2x)^(x/2))/2)

another way

log(x,2log(2x, 2log(2,4x)))=log(x,log(2x, (log(2,(4x)^2))^2))

but all of them is incorrect

please help me

i need it

it's so hard i think

Comment: What do you mean by $\log (2, 4x)$? Also check out the mathJax tutorial :)

Comment: log(2,4x) means  (log4x)/(log2)

Comment: So log(a, b) = $\log_a(b)$?

Comment: yes exactly  
yes yes yes